# Can i graft a pineapple and watermelon together? Since the both berries

Tags: fruit-trees

I'd it possible because one person I know thinks it is but I don't want to trust the opinion of one person so like is it true or not

Can you graft watermelon together with pineapple

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Pineapple/watermelon grafts go around as one of those crazy clickbaity things on the internet.  Here's an example where they rub aloe vera in the rind of a watermelon and then plant a pineapple in it, ha!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgVzQMS3zOo

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/985/why-did-this-ignorant-question-receive-such-a-poor-response

Answer (score 4):

No - Melons are members of the  Cucurbitaceae and Pineapple is a member of a completely different plant Family, the Bromeliaceae,  so they are not compatible graft partners. If you like though, check out the Tiktok videos on line that profess to show  you how to do it successfully if you want to experience whether it's possible.